# facebook gift application

Tags: php, facebook

want to create an application in facebook it simply select the images from the available option and i can send that gift to my frinds like in this apps

http://apps.facebook.com/ecardsforallcechefeg/

Comment: Cool! so whats your question?

Comment: Even if there were a question here, I wouldn't attempt to answer with 53 questions, only 3 answers and 7 upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altought the question is not really asked - maybe this helps some lonely google searcher:

The Developer Area of Facebook is a good entry point: http://developers.facebook.com/ (if unsure go to the wiki)

If you really just want to do a quick app try the Generator Apps - quick google search found that one: maybe it helps/works
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=8089123087

Good luck.